# Derivative of $v_{l}(r) = - \frac{1}{2} h(r)^T \left[H +\frac{Mr}{2} I \right]h(r) - \frac{M}{12}r^3$ w.r.t. $r$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I am reading this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0706-8) (Section 5.1) and in some point it is stated that the derivative of $$v_{l}(r) = - \frac{1}{2}g^T \left[H +\frac{Mr}{2} I \right]^{-1}g - \frac{M}{12}r^3 \tag{1}$$ w.r.t. r is

$$v_{l}'(r) = \frac{M}{4} (||h(r)||^2-r^2) \tag{2}$$ with

$$g = -H h(r) - \frac{M}{2}r h(r). \tag{3}$$ and

$$h(r) \stackrel{(3)}{=} -\left[ H+ \frac{Mr}{2}I\right]^{-1}g.\tag{4}$$

Using $(4)$ in $(1)$, I have tried the following

$$\begin{aligned}\partial_{r} v_{l}(r) =& \partial_r\left[-\frac{1}{2} h(r)^T\left(H+\frac{Mr}{2}I \right) h(r) -\frac{M}{12}r^3\right]
\\ = & -\frac{1}{2} \left(\partial_{r} \left(h(r)^T H h(r)\right)+\frac{Mr}{2} \partial_{r} ||h(r)||^2\right)-\frac{M}{4}r^2 \\ =& -\frac{1}{2} \left[ h(r)^TH \partial_r h(r)+ \frac{Mr}{2} h(r)^T \partial_r h(r)\right]-\frac{M}{4}r^2 \\ =&  -\frac{1}{2} h(r)^T \left[H + \frac{Mr}{2}I \right]\partial_r h(r)-\frac{M}{4}r^2\end{aligned}$$ but I could not reach $(2)$. Can you please give some directions? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Let $J=H+MIr/2$. Then $g=-Jh$ so $v_l(r)=-\langle h,Jh\rangle/2-Mr^3/12$. However I do not see how $\partial_r\langle h,Jh\rangle=-M\|h\|^2/2$.

Comment: I do not think the statement is true as the last inequality requires $\partial_r\langle h,Hh\rangle=-M\|h\|^2$ but $H,h$ are independent of $M$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks for the response, i did some changes after your comments. Could you please verify? I think I need $\partial_r h(r)$ in $(4)$ now but I do not know how to compute it. Any additional comments please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\d#1{{\dot #1}}
$For ease of typing, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \tfrac 12M, \qquad
K &= -(H+\l rI)^{-1}, \qquad
h &= Kg \\
}$$
and use a dot to denote the derivative with respect to $r$
$$\eqalign{
\d K &= -K\d K^{-1}K =  +\l K^2 \\
\d h &= \LR{K\d g + \d Kg} = \LR{K\d g + \l K^2g} \\
   &= K\LR{\d g + \l h} \\
\d g &= \LR{K^{-1}\d h - \l h} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function and calculate its derivative.
$$\eqalign{
v &= \frac 12g^Th - \frac 16\l r^3 \\
\d v &= \frac12\LR{g^T\d h+h^T\d g - \l r^2} \\
}$$
This straightforward result can be rewritten solely in terms of the parameters $(g,\d g)$ or the parameters $(h,\d h).\;$ Neither form matches the result quoted from the pay-walled paper,

but the $h$-parameterization comes closest
$$\eqalign{
\d v &= \frac12\LR{2h^TK^{-1}\d h - \l h^Th - \l r^2} \\
 &= \LR{h^TK^{-1}\d h} - \frac{\l}2\Big(\|h\|^2 +r^2\Big) \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please give me some time to read it carefully.

Comment: Could you please give some more details on how $K = -K \dot{K}^{-1} K =  +\lambda K^2$ is derived?

Comment: Simply differentiating the definition of the inverse one obtains
$$\eqalign{
&I = KK^{-1} \\
&0 = \dot KK^{-1} + K\dot K^{-1} \\
&\dot K = -K\dot K^{-1}K \\
}$$
Likewise, the definition of $K$ yields
$$\eqalign{
&K^{-1} = -(H+\lambda rI)\quad\implies\quad
\dot K^{-1} = -\lambda I \quad\implies\quad
\dot K = +\lambda K^2 \\
}$$

Comment: Got it. Another question. According to the paper, $h$ is a function of $r$ while $g$ is not. Can we say that $\dot{h} = K(\dot{g}+\lambda h) = K\lambda h$? I think if we state that and replace it in you last relation about $\dot{v}$ we can conclude to $\dot{v} = \frac{M}{4} (||h(r)||^2-r^2)$. Could you please verify?

Comment: Yes. That important piece of information should've been provided in your post, since not everyone has access to the linked paper.